# Why doesn't rsync --delete delete some files?

Tags: backup, rsync

I use rsync to backup my photo directory containing JPEGs as well as RAWs organized like this:

```
Pictures
+--older_folder
   +--a.jpg
   +--b.jpg
+--newer_folder
   +--c.jpg
   +--d.jpg
   +--RAW
      +--c.RAW
      +--d.RAW
```

After each backup, I delete the local RAW files as they are too large for my system, so in the example above, the older folder has already been updated, the newer one has not. So the backup drive before using rsync looks like this:

```
/mnt/e/
+--older_folder
   +--a.jpg
   +--b.jpg
   +--RAW
      +--a.RAW
      +--b.RAW
```

In the backup, I want to keep all RAW files - so when I used the command `rsync -axPEh --stats --delete -b --backup-dir=/mnt/e/backup ./Pictures/ /mnt/e/`, I expected a.RAW and b.RAW to be moved into the `/mnt/e/backup` folder, which did not happen - why?

(Just as a side note, other files that I had also deleted locally were actually moved into the `/mnt/e/backup` - so magically, rsync did exactly what I wanted it to do, I just cannot explain this behaviour.)

Comment: Do you mean "I expected c.RAW and d.RAW to be moved into the backup folder, which did not happen"? Are you sure that you want to use --delete (because it tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but only for the directories  that are being synchronized. Is that really what you want? And please notice that --delete is risky.

Comment: Sorry - no, I meant a.RAW and b.RAW, but I meant the `/mnt/e/backup` folder (bad nomenclature of mine there, but edited that in the original post).
Yes, I know that --delete is dangerous, that's why I also use -b

Comment: I am using a daily set of backup directories (for files that might be overwritten). Maybe I am too tired, but this is how I understand it: Those RAW files are already there and will not be replaced so no need to move them to avoid that they get overwritten. `--delete` is only acting on what is actively backed up. See the description in `man rsync`.